# Warnings from perl threads::shared

Tags: multithreading, perl, warnings, shared

My pseudo code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5.8.8
use warnings;
use strict;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub tasker;

my @allThreads = ();
my @array = ('alpha','beta','gamma');
push @allThreads, threads->new(\&tasker, @array);
$_->join foreach @allThreads;

sub tasker{
    my @localArray = @_;

    ...call some other modules/functions...

}
```

While the threads are running, I get these messages after a few seconds on my STDOUT:

```
Still here!
Still here!
Still here!
```

After which the threads join (complete) successfully. I am not sure where these are coming from and why they show up only for some @array. A point to mention is that the number of these messages is equal to the elements in @array.

Will appreciate any help from experts.

Comment: Aside from the redundant `join` at line 13 there's nothing in the code you've provided that would cause those messages. Since you're only creating one thread, it's apparent that whatever creates one of those messages per element in the array happens at `...call some other modules/functions...`.

Comment: Hum, why was my Answer changed to a a comment? The OP wants to locate some leftover debugging code, and I showed him how to do just that. reposting while making that clear.

Comment: @flesk: Sorry for wasting your time ! I got the culprit. It was indeed in the `...call some other modules/functions...` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (or one of the module you are using) appears to have some leftover debugging code. To locate it, add

```
INIT { print "$0\n"; print "$_\n" for values %INC; exit }
```

to your script. Pipe the output to

```
xargs grep 'Still here!'
```

Then remove the debugging code.

PS - If you use `warn` without a trailing newline, your debugging messages will have a file name and line number attached. This can be useful :)

Comment: Ok, my bad ! I just did a grep on my entire code base and found the culprit. I was dumb (and in a lot of hurry to get things done) to ask this question. Sorry, again ! But I like your suggestion to `use warn` to get file name and the line number for such messages.

Comment: @Wilderness, I meant "If you use `warn` without a trailing *newline*", although `warn` with no args is also useful.